# Can chisel print time like verilog

Tags: chisel

In digital circuit simulation verification, time is a very important parameter. Verilog can use the $time function to obtain simulation time. I want to know if chisel has the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that Chisel has this functionality. However if there is something you need to use this for inside of a design, you can always create a Chisel `BlackBox` and include the `$time` print in that.

Chisel *generally* only prints synthesizable Verilog. That being said, it's possible someone has a library that includes this and can extend the print through a FIRRTL transform.